# mysql change multiple columns with condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I want to change two columns when the condition is true, but that didn't work:

```
UPDATE product 
 SET last_bidder=CASE WHEN deadline>'2014-06-05 11:53:51' AND price=90 
                      THEN 'pepe@gmil.com' 
                      ELSE last_bidder END 
WHERE product_id=41
```

Thanx for help me.

Comment: May I ask which two columns you're trying to change and into what?

Comment: I want to change column last_bidder and price when deadline>x thx.

Comment: just add brackets `(` `)`

Comment: UPDATE product SET last_bidder='pepe',price=90 WHERE product_id=41 AND  deadline>'2014-06-05 11:53:51' 

I think this is the solution, thx all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question;

Price is currently in your CASE condition, but needs to be in the SET part. You also want to update *all* fields if and only if the deadline hasn't passed, so just put the condition in the `WHERE` clause;

```
UPDATE product SET price = 90, last_bidder = 'pepe@gmil.com' 
WHERE product_id = 41 AND deadline > '2014-06-05 11:53:51'
```

Comment: i think title is misleading, he just want to set `last_bidder` based on case conditions...

Comment: @Peter Seems this is correct, since the OP added a comment with pretty much the same query a few seconds after this answer.